# Entity diagrams in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5, graphics, diagram

What's the best way/tool to display nice diagrams with entity relationships in ASP MVC views?  
i.e. servers and and applications, or servers with other servers.

Are there any third party tools out there that can do this?  
I've been searching around things like Telerik, but it's really hard to google for this!

Answer (score 3):

Here are some 3rd-party diagramming tools:

- http://www.nevron.com/Products.DiagramFor.NET.Overview.aspx
- http://www.nwoods.com/GO/dotnet.htm
- http://www.syncfusion.com/products/diagram/web/default.aspx